# How to enforce mandatory argument in Typescript Function Type?

Tags: typescript

I am new to Typescript and have a doubt regarding function type.

I have the following type :

```
type IMyTest<R> = (
    arg1: number,
    arg2: string,
    arg3: number
) => R;
```

Now, following signature is valid (doesn't give me an error) and I don't understand why its valid. As per my understandings, `arg2` and `arg3` are not marked as optional using the "?" sign and so the TypeScript compiler should raise an error, but it's not:

```
const myTest3: IMyTest<string> = (arg1: number):string => {

    return "any string";
};
```

[Live example on the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=2&pc=22#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgsiAKhAzsAPAJQHxQLxQAUAUFGVAIYBOA5gIwBcUAdgK4C2ARhFQDSnlqNAExM0VAJbMa-cpVoBmJmy49iASny5MAbmLEAxgHtmaKOySpgS2AmRp04qTVwFCQxiw7cq6hk+ktKABvfTkqCGBWKmYoACIKZhAoAJo4vQBfHSA)

Is there any way to make the arguments mandatory ?

Right now, arg1?:string is same as arg1:string.  According to my understandings,without the "?" sign, an argument is mandatory. But, that's not the case in here.

Comment: You can call the function with 3 arguments and it would be fine, hence it's valid. You can always pass more arguments than necessary.

Comment: Ya. But, is there any way to make the arguments mandatory ? Right now, arg1?:string is same as arg1:string.  According to my understandings,without the "?" sign, an argument is mandatory. But, that's not the case in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at type compatibility [rules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions)

```
let x = (a: number) => 0;
let y = (b: number, s: string) => 0;

y = x; // OK
x = y; // Error
```

"Discarding" parameters (like in your example) is allowed because the implementation doesn't care if these parameters provided or not (you won't get any error at runtime).

> This pattern is actually quite common in JavaScript. For example, [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) provides three parameters to the callback function: the array element, its index, and the containing array. Nevertheless, it’s very useful to provide a callback that only uses the first parameter.

```
const items = [1, 2, 3];

// Don't force these extra parameters
items.forEach((item, index, array) => console.log(item));

// Should be OK!
items.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

Comment: Btw, you mean y == x and x == y, right ? Is there anyway to make the arguments mandatory ? Thanks.

Comment: This explains why it works, but the question is how to require that the function have those parameters. Are you saying it's not possible? (That would surprise me, given how powerful TypeScript is.)

Comment: _Btw, you mean y == x and x == y?_ **No** I'm explaining why assignment is allowed

Comment: @AlekseyL. Ya. You are right. My mistake. Thanks. I found a solution. Though I can write the function by omitting the arguments, but, I can't call it without providing 3 arguments. It does make sense now.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you're right. But do you have any example when it would be useful? (require implementation to have those parameters)

Comment: @AlekseyL. - Not offhand, no. :-) But I still want to know if it's possible.

Comment: Hi everyone, i think it is still important to clarify if there is a solution? i've read the answer and the discussion, it gives me some explanations but there is no answer yet ?

Comment: Looks like it is not possible, but also looks like there's no real use case for such requirement.